# Best practive for testng Architecture

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm using Selenium-Webdriver / Testng / Eclipse / java to create my tests. I started out with 1 class and just added code to navigate and test the functionality. Then I create multiple methods tagged @Test. This was obviously better since I can run individual tests with flags such as @Test(priority = 8, enabled = true) or from an XML file that lists the methods to run.

Having 1 class and currently 15 tests is now getting a bit hard to maintain. Do people tend to break out the tests to more classes? Each class containing related tests? or each test to a class and grouping classes to run?

Answer (score 1):

You should be consider using [Page Object](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) pattern in your project.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on following factors : project complexity, programming style, future maintenance. If the project is fair enough with regards to above factors then you can create separate feature based classes, have multiple classes grouped in to one group based on feature or requirement. You can have your common tests in base test class and other test classes to extend that class. So basically it depends on your requirement.
Let me know if this helps by accepting this as answer.